# How to sniff download information of different pc's on a network(router)

Tags: logs, tcpdump, wireshark

Actually I am making an Log Analyzer for downloads on a network by different users.So i want to know who downloaded what in a same network.I know SSL packets cannot be sniffed but I want only downloads that is not secured by SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a switch that support [Port Mirroring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) you could do the following way

- Create a mirror port of your uplink, or if you have multiple level of switches(core, distribution, dep) make a mirror of your internet facing port to another port of this switch.
- Install [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) on your *NIX system. It is a pretty good tool to create statistics about traffic.

Other ways you could do this:

- Install ntop at your firewall, if the internet link is directly connected to it
- Configure [sFlow/NetFlow](http://www.thenoccave.com/2010/11/14/know-whats-flowing-on-your-network/) on your router to redirect traffic information to your ntop server.

Since `tcpdump` is a tool for packet analyze/inspection, it will be harder to display URL, times of download and other things that are more "high-level" and more usefull to your reports.